# Remove Facebook Comments from Site

Tags: html, facebook, comments, facebook-comments

I've got the basic comment box on my site. NOT attached to an app or part of one (as I don't develop apps).

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

                                <script>(function(d, s, id) {
                                  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                                  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                                  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                                  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
                                  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                                }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

                                <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.-----.com/tech" data-num-posts="3" data-width="500" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

In the head tag:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="My User ID"/>
```

Now, when someone comments on a friend's comment, I don't want that to show on my site. How the heck can I remove the comments from my site!? This is driving me insane.

So other than this https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments, what can I do to remove some of these comments?

Comment: Well didn't you answer your question already ? The comment-tools from facebook is the choice! Otherwise you can also just go on the page with the comment-box itself and there change the view to 'moderator mode' or similar and do the same there.

Comment: I have no options to do any sort of moderation from my webpage.

Comment: Ah silly me, didn't read carefully enough. Answer follows in a minute...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that you have replaced the code with your user_id from facebook

You can find out your user id by going to the following address:
http://graph.facebook.com/[YOUR USERNAME]

For example, mine is http://graph.facebook.com/coulton resulting in the following.

`<meta property="fb:admins" content="543270572"/>`

This must be in the  tag of the page which contains the Comments plugin

Now when you're logged in to Facebook with this account, you will see a "moderator view" button appear at the top of the comments window.

[image: Moderator view button]

You should now see the interface to edit the comments from your site.

Comment: Already there. <meta property="fb:admins" content="501999667"/>.

Comment: Are you currently logged in to Facebook with that account?

Comment: Yep! I can even comment on my own, AND I can remove my own.

Comment: Have you visited the page which actually has the plugin installed on, and seen if the "Moderator View" button is there?  You won't be able to edit from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments without having the fb:app_id specified.

Answer (score 1):

Also when you don't develop an app on FB, you can use the comments-tool from facebook and it's what I strongly recommend, because it's the easiest one. The comment-box itself can be registered to an app and you don't need to write a real app to use it, that's just what Facebook calls it.

So therefore you just create an 'app', which is only responsible for comment administration. Create an app and register it in your meta-tags with fb:app_id on your page with the comment box! Instantly you can use it to moderate all your comments.

The other solution is to be logged in with the user defined in the fb:admins tag and go to the comment box and choose moderation view. Use the tips mentioned by Coulton. Use the [debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to see if everything is set up right.

Comment: Somehow it ALL randomly showed up after logging out twice and re-logging in. Haha, ahhh technology.

Comment: I still recommend using the comments-tool, just really useful when you are having more than just one box, plus you get notified on your fb profile and can moderate just right from there.

Comment: I use the same, I can see all of my website's comments.  woop!

Comment: I have been messing with the comments tool. I already had a random app created. Only problem I have is that when adding my domains, after saving and going back, the domains disappear.

Comment: If you are really speaking of the plural of domain...you can't do that! Only add the domain without paths like www.example.com (not www.example.com/file.php), it's just for redirecting purposes anyway, you should be able to link the comments-boxes of two different sites (domains) to the same app.

Comment: I did it such as site.com, site2.com. I have a couple domain names that point to the same site, but don't redirect the url.

Comment: Yeah only use ONE domain in the app, the others will work though anyway as long as they point to the same app. The reason why you define a URL in your app is just to redirect from the app to the page - not the other way round. For the purposes you use the app it's unneccesary anyway...

Comment: I tried using just one, still the same issue, it clears out automatically?

Comment: You need to enter your domain on the bottom where it says [Website] Site URL:, not the app domain!

Comment: Offtopic, but looking at your stack overflow profile, you should accept and/or upvote answers when they were helpful. That's how the whole thing here works :)

Comment: Definitely will do! I tend to forget on that piece. Thanks again!